# Conversion hex string into ascii in bash command line

Tags: bash, hex

I have a lot of this kind of string and I want to find a command to convert it in ascii, I tried with `echo -e` and `od`, but it did not work.

```
0xA7.0x9B.0x46.0x8D.0x1E.0x52.0xA7.0x9B.0x7B.0x31.0xD2
```

Comment: That does not look like ASCII. ASCII is not defined for values greater than 0x7f.

Comment: do you mean it's binary?

Comment: Do you mean int/binary instead of ASCII? The values you have shown are greater than ASCII range...

Comment: What would you expect to get for your example string?

Comment: i would expect a printable string but it is not...it should be a clear text password. But from what you said i guess is encrypted or hashed (binary version)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
$ echo 54657374696e672031203220330 | xxd -r -p
Testing 1 2 3$
```

`-r` tells it to convert hex to ascii as opposed to its normal mode of doing the opposite

`-p` tells it to use a plain format.

Comment: `pbpaste | xxd -rp` from Homebrew on Mac didn't work but `pbpaste | xxd -r -p` did ..........

Comment: Watch out! `echo` adds a newline char to the end of everything it prints. Technically, this is more correct: `printf "%s" "54657374696e672031203220330" | xxd -r -p` since it doesn't add the newline char.

Comment: Also, for anyone wondering, here's how to go from the binary string (ASCII chars) to ASCII hex: `printf "%s" "Testing 1 2 3" | xxd -p`. Output: `54657374696e67203120322033`. If you do `echo` instead, you get the stray hex `0a` at the end, which is the newling `\n` char. `echo "Testing 1 2 3" | xxd -p` results in `54657374696e672031203220330a`.

Comment: `echo -n text` avoids the newline, shorter than printf.

Answer (score 28):

This code will convert the text `0xA7.0x9B.0x46.0x8D.0x1E.0x52.0xA7.0x9B.0x7B.0x31.0xD2` into a stream of 11 bytes with equivalent values.  These bytes will be written to standard out.

```
TESTDATA=$(echo '0xA7.0x9B.0x46.0x8D.0x1E.0x52.0xA7.0x9B.0x7B.0x31.0xD2' | tr '.' ' ')
for c in $TESTDATA; do
    echo $c | xxd -r
done
```

As others have pointed out, this will not result in a printable ASCII string for the simple reason that the specified bytes are not ASCII.  You need post more information about how you obtained this string for us to help you with that.

How it works:  xxd -r translates hexadecimal data to binary (like a reverse hexdump).  xxd requires that each line start off with the index number of the first character on the line (run hexdump on something and see how each line starts off with an index number).  In our case we want that number to always be zero, since each execution only has one line.  As luck would have it, our data already has zeros before every character as part of the 0x notation.  The lower case x is ignored by xxd, so all we have to do is pipe each 0xhh character to xxd and let it do the work.

The tr translates periods to spaces so that for will split it up correctly.

Comment: not working for me with xxd --version = `xxd V1.10 27oct98` on newish Redhat linux (with ksh). I just get one § char.

Comment: That is exactly what I get too.  The data is not text, so it does not print out very well.  To see it in a printable form, put my code into a bash function, like danstest() { ... }.  Then, call the function and pipe the output to hexdump -C.  This will show you byte-for-byte what data is coming out of my code.

Comment: cool. You can just do ` ... done | hexdump -C`, no function needed. Good luck to all.

Comment: needed to use `xxd -r -p` to get string output from "xxd V1.10 27oct98"

Answer (score 19):

You can use `xxd`:

```
$cat hex.txt
68 65 6c 6c 6f
$cat hex.txt | xxd -r -p
hello
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like this.

```
$ cat test_file.txt
54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 74 65 78 74 20 64 61 74 61 2e 0a 4f 6e 65 20 6d 6f 72 65 20 6c 69 6e 65 20 6f 66 20 74 65 73 74 20 64 61 74 61 2e

$ for c in `cat test_file.txt`; do printf "\x$c"; done;
This is text data.
One more line of test data.
```

Comment: I'm trying to decode mysterious data from a game (Elite: Dangerous) that looks like decimal, this seems to work (with `\\ ` instead of `\x`). (:

Answer (score 7):

The values you provided are UTF-8 values. When set, the array of:

```
declare -a ARR=(0xA7 0x9B 0x46 0x8D 0x1E 0x52 0xA7 0x9B 0x7B 0x31 0xD2)
```

Will be parsed to print the plaintext characters of each value.

```
for ((n=0; n < ${#ARR[*]}; n++)); do echo -e "\u${ARR[$n]//0x/}"; done
```

And the output will yield a few printable characters and some non-printable characters as shown here:

[image]

For converting hex values to plaintext using the `echo` command:

```
echo -e "\x<hex value here>"
```

And for converting UTF-8 values to plaintext using the `echo` command:

```
echo -e "\u<UTF-8 value here>"
```

And then for converting octal to plaintext using the `echo` command:

```
echo -e "\0<octal value here>"
```

When you have encoding values you aren't familiar with, take the time to check out the ranges in the common encoding schemes to determine what encoding a value belongs to. Then conversion from there is a snap.

Answer (score 4):

The `echo -e` must have been failing for you because of wrong escaping.
The following code works fine for me on a similar output from `your_program with arguments`:

```
echo -e $(your_program with arguments | sed -e 's/0x\(..\)\.\?/\\x\1/g')
```

Please note however that your original hexstring consists of non-printable characters.

Answer (score 2):

Make a script like this:

```
bash
#!/bin/bash

echo $((0x$1)).$((0x$2)).$((0x$3)).$((0x$4))
```

Example:

```
sh converthextoip.sh c0 a8 00 0b
```

Result:

```
192.168.0.11
```