# Grep for variable hex value

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to count the number of times a hex value appears in a file.  The hex value is set in a variable.

Using the literal string "x01" returns the correct count:

```
grep -o $'\x01' ${fileName} | wc -l
```

How can I use a variable in place of ***x01*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from [Conversion hex string into ascii in bash command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160309/conversion-hex-string-into-ascii-in-bash-command-line)

```sh
# single quote character in hex
$ a='\x27'

$ echo "a'b'c" | grep -o $(echo "$a" | xxd -r -p)
'
'

$ echo "a'b'c" | grep -o $(echo "$a" | xxd -r -p) | wc -l
2

# you can also use just the number, \x prefix is optional
$ echo "a'b'c" | grep -o $(echo '27' | xxd -r -p) | wc -l
2

# if PCRE is available
$ echo "a'b'c" | grep -oP "$a" | wc -l
2

# with ripgrep (https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)
$ echo "a'b'c" | rg -oc "$a"
2
```

Comment: Thanks using your answer, I think this will work for me:
grep -Fo  $(echo "${delim1}" | xxd -r -p)  ${filename} | wc -l

Comment: @Fiddlestiques that's because grep removes the newline before searching and adds it back when printing